# Can I use a regex to insert text between numbers and letters in a string?

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to use regex to insert a space and "|" between a letter and a number in a string?

For example `EA412` would become `EA | 412`.

Comment: Will the string always be some letters followed by some numbers, and nothing else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, for example using [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or [`replaceFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). For example:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])", " | ");
```

(Assuming "letter" means A-Z or a-z and "number" means a digit 0-9.)

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/Kl0hW)

Comment: Wow! You guys are fast! That's perfect! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("EA412".replaceFirst("(\\D{2})", "$1 | "));
```